# Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 when trying to return Excel spreadhsheet

Tags: django, excel, ember.js, response

I have an emberJS application where I can make a POST AJAX call to a Django backend. A function in Django creates an xlsx file for a bunch of queried items based on IDs coming in the POST request. It goes through the Django view function without any issues, but when the HTTP response is returned to ember, I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery.js:8787)
    at done (jquery.js:9255)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9548)
    at XMLHttpRequest.nrWrapper (base-content:20)
```

I'm setting the response content type to application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, so I'm unsure as to why its trying to read the response as JSON.

**Python Code**

```
file_path = '/User/path_to_spreadsheet/content.xlsx'
fsock = open(file_path, "rb")

response = HttpResponse(fsock, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="content.xlsx"'
return response
```

**EmberJS Code**

```
export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    storeProductId(products) {
      let product_ids = []

      products.forEach(function(product){
        product_ids.push(product.id)
      });

      let adapter = this.store.adapterFor('product-export');
      adapter.export_products(product_ids).then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
      }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log('ERROR')
        console.log(response)
      })
    }
  }
});
```

**Product-Export Adapter Code**

```
export default ApplicationAdapter.extend(FormDataAdapterMixin, {
  export_products(products) {
    let url = this.buildURL('unified-product');
    url = `${url}export/`;
    return this.ajax(url, 'POST', { data: {'products': products} });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the "product-export" adapter code as well?

Comment: Hey Igor, I added the product-export adapter code to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Ember Data makes some assumptions around how things should be handled (including that you’ll be receiving JSON data back). Is there a reason you are using Ember Data instead of using a direct Ajax call to your backend? Seems like that would greatly simplify things here ...